# Why can not use "title" as referencing outlet of UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, iboutlet

I have one `UITextField` and it's referencing outlet name title.
when i use title as a outlet it crashes my application.
and gives error 
`[UITextField isEqualToString] NSInvalidArgument` etc.

and when I use titles it work fine.
I search more in google for reserved words in ios and there i not found that title is a reserved word.
so please anybody knows about this simple issue than please share it with me.
I know this is simple issue but I'm new in ios development and right now I'm trainee developer so for me this is a big issue because I want to know why this title word as a referencing outlet not working.

Thank You!

Comment: It's recommended that variable name should contain the type of it. Because if you have in your app UILabel called "title" and UITextField called the same - you will be confused. Name it titleLabel or titleTextField and there will be no problems. Also make sure that you compare content of UITextField, not UITextField itself 'if (titleTextField.text isEqualToString:@"string") {}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this on a class that extends `UIViewController`, the problem is that `UIViewController` already has a property named `title` with a type of `NSString`.

By adding an outlet for a `UITextField` with a name of `title`, you are creating a conflict with the `NSString` property named `title`.

Simply give your outlet a name that doesn't conflict with an existing property name.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing knowledge with me and others.